# let user choose a file and open it later

Tags: android

I want to let the user choose a file using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/json");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and then somehow save the path to this file, so that i can open it anytime.

I tried saving the uri string but when i want to access the file with that later, i get an permission denial exception.
I also tried using uri.getPath() to create a `File` instance, but that didn't work either.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Answer (score 1):

In onActivityResult you should take persistable uri permission in order to use the saved uri.toString() later.

Permissions in manifest are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Manifest contains the permissions required for accessing storage.
Then ask the user to give you the permission using alertDialog and this code

```
String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
requestPermissions(permissions, 10);
```

Then check like that

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

for every permission, you ask, every time you use the storage.
Now you might be able to access the storage.